# Is there a Maven equivalent of "gradle dependencyInsight"?

Tags: maven, gradle

In gradle, the command `gradle dependencyInsight --dependency <artifact-name>` prints a reverse dependency graph for a specific artifact.

Is there something equivalent in Maven?

I'm aware of `mvn dependency:tree`. This is the equivalent of `gradle dependencies`. However this is not what I'm asking about.

Comment: `mvn dependency:list` does this help you?

Comment: It would help to explain what you're looking for, without assuming that Maven users are familiar with Gradle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use [filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/filtering-the-dependency-tree.html) with maven dependency plugin

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=[groupId]:[artifactId]:[type]:[version]
```

Check the link, there is an example. The output isn't actually in reverse but it shouldn't be too hard to read it in reverse by yourself.

Eclipse-IDE has some nice features which allows dependencies to tracked without using command line. Open pom.xml, open dependency hierarchy tab and there, dependencies can be filtered. Other IDEs might have similar features as well.

Comment: Thanks! It's just what I've needed :-)